# InnerKeySelector and OuterKeySelector of Join query not showing intellisense, it shows "(parameter) ?"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, join, asp.net-core

In the code below I want to join three lists and get country name and sector name for a given port id.

When I hover above the `po` parameter in Visual Studio it shows `(parameter) ?po` since it cannot find the type of `po`.

[image: (parameter)?po]

What's wrong with my code?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class port
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int countryid { get; set; }
        public int sectorid { get; set; }
    }
    class country
    {
        public int countryid { get; set; }
        public string countryname { get; set; }
    }

    class sector
    {
        public int sectorid { get; set; }
        public string sectorname { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<port> portlist = new List<port>()
            {
              new port { id=1,countryid=1,sectorid=1},
            };

            IList<sector> sectorlist = new List<sector>()
            {
              new sector {sectorid=1,sectorname="chennai"},
               new sector {sectorid=2,sectorname="mumbai"},
            };

            IList<country> countrylist = new List<country>()
            {
              new country {countryid=1,countryname="india"},
              new country {countryid=2,countryname="pakistan"},
            };

            var result = portlist.Join(sectorlist, po => po.)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you were actually tried to do with `portlist.Join`

Comment: And What would be the expected output